# Any way to make rails not generate a `schema_migrations` table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using Rails 3 for a project but I am not using migrations (for reasons that aren't relevant to the question). Rather, I'm just editing `schema.rb` and running `rake db:create db:schema:load` each time I make a change to the schema.

However, on inspection with phpMyAdmin, it looks like Rails is still creating a table called `schema_migrations`. Is there a quick way for me to turn this off while still using the `schema.rb` DSL? I have no problem going down to an SQL file for creating my database but I'd rather not have to do that.